# html javascript editor

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I would like to get the same type of functionality as the SO editor (including the preview) for my own site. Is it a separate project that has been incorporated into SO that I can use too? Or is it designed by SO, and if so can I get it and use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editor used by SO is [WMD Markdown editor](http://wmd-editor.com/).

Checkout this post for more info:

- [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

The code syntax highlighter used is:

- [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

**To get the similar preview effect, check out this post:**

- [Syntax Highlighting a la StackOverflow with Google Prettify](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/syntax-highlighting-stackoverflow-google-prettify)

Comment: The link you provided is for an open source project, but the post you provided says that they rewrote a closed source editor for SO. Is it the same thing?